# is my JAVA_HOME path incorrect?

Tags: path, bash

This is a step in :
http://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/google-native.html

Im trying to generate an SH1 key with:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

I get the following error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/alex_fimm_dev/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/alex_fimm_dev/.android/debug.keystore
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:745)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)
```

I suspect something is wrong with JAVA_HOME path?

here is my .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/alex_fimm_dev/Desktop/Databases/Mongo/mongodb/bin:/Users/alex_fimm_dev/Desktop/Databases/Mongo/mongodb/bin

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# android and java paths
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home/
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/platform-tools:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/tools
```

And if I go to the location of the keystore file:

```
lm5-fim4-0G3QD:~ alex_fimm_dev$ cd ~/.android/
lm5-fim4-0G3QD:.android alex_fimm_dev$ keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/Home/bin/bin/keytool" (-1)
lm5-fim4-0G3QD:.android alex_fimm_dev$
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Update path in all my terminals like:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

generate `.keystore` which was missing in ~/.android like:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

your java and android path is like this::

`ANDROID_HOME=/home/user_name/Android/Sdk`

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

If want it to make it permanent just add those lines in the ~/.bashrc file